# Multiple ONNX models using opencv and c++ for inference

Tags: c++, opencv, model, onnx

I am trying to load, multiple ONNX models, whereby I can process different inputs inside the same algorithm. Let's assume that model 1 would receive as input an image and output a set of 6 values (int) related to this image. The second model would also receive an image but output a binary classification instead.

So far, I have managed to successfully run on a single model. However when I try to load the second one I got an error:

```
// Load first .onnx model using OpenCV's DNN module
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNet("model_1.onnx");
net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT);
net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);

// Load second .onnx model using OpenCV's DNN module
cv::dnn::Net net_2 = cv::dnn::readNet("model_2.onnx");
net_2.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT);
net_2.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);
```

Everything runs without errors until this point. But I got errors when trying to retrieve data from the second model.

```
// Forward first model
 net.setInput(blob);
 net.forward(output_blobs, output_names);
// Forward second model
 net_2.setInput(blob);
 net_2.forward(output_blobs_2, output_names_2);
```

Any help or advice will be more than welcome.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DoNetNuke, so the tag should be removed.

Comment: which error do you get? Do both models use the same input shape (blob size, number of channels etc.)? Does it work if you create a second input blob instead of re-using the same blob? Does your code work if you only use the second model (instead of only using the first model)?

Comment: Hi @Micka I am getting the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA960C467C in vision_test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000001F1A9857D0. I got this error even when creating a second input blob and yes, the code works using only the second model.  I appreciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: @JoeCraig, sorry the tag went by mistake. Thanks for point this out, I have now fixed the tag issue.

Comment: Please make sure that you aren't using debug libraries in release build or vice-versa if using Windows MSVC runtime DLLs. I dont know whether there is any interaction or shared resources between different opencv DNN instances, sorry.

Comment: @Micka, thanks for your comments. I have double-checked the libraries and they have not been swapped, so this would not be an issue. Interesting is that it is possible to import two or more models using ORT, but I am curious to find a way to do it using OpenCV, and I have been looking for this for quite some time without any success.

Comment: Can you put your code in a try-catch block and print the std::exception::what() result after catching?